Using the Babylonian method to find the square root gives wrong results
I feel like I have everything right I just can't seem to get the square root right. Every time I run it the answer is off.
For example, when I plug in 100 it spits out 26 as the square root, which isn't correct.
What I am doing wrong?
def sqrt(n):
    nextGuess = n / 2
    lastGuess = 1
    accuracy = 0.000001
    while lastGuess > accuracy:
        x = (lastGuess + n / lastGuess) / 2
        lastGuess = nextGuess - x
        nextGuess = x
        return x

n = float(input('Enter a value:'))
if n <= 0:
    print('Invalid number. Enter a positive number.')
else:
    print(sqrt(n))


you have two errors in your code: first your return statement is misindented, and second your lastGuess should use abs
def sqrt(n):
    nextGuess= n/2
    lastGuess=1
    accuracy= 0.000001
    while lastGuess > accuracy:
        x = (lastGuess + n/ lastGuess) / 2
        lastGuess = abs(nextGuess - x)
        nextGuess = x
    return x


sqrt(18) says 7.598860361987932

You don't need to have learned about a specific algorithm to necessarily implement it. Some print statements will show what's wrong with your code.
Looking at your while loop:
while lastGuess > accuracy:
    x = (lastGuess + n/ lastGuess) / 2
    lastGuess = nextGuess - x
    nextGuess = x
    return x  # This shouldn't be indented

By having the return within the while loop, you're not looping, you're just returning. So let's fix that and print a couple of things
[131]: def sqrt(n):
     ...:     nextGuess= n/2
     ...:     lastGuess=1
     ...:     accuracy= 0.000001
     ...:     while lastGuess > accuracy:
     ...:         x = (lastGuess + n/ lastGuess) / 2
     ...:         lastGuess = nextGuess - x
     ...:         nextGuess = x
     ...:         print(x, lastGuess, nextGuess)
     ...:     return x
     ...:

[132]: sqrt(100)
50.5 -0.5 50.5
Out[132]: 50.5

So your lastGuess immediately drops below accuracy, stopping the loop. You don't want to check if the last guess is bigger than the accuracy, but rather if the difference between x_n and x_{n-1} is less than your accuracy. So let's make a delta variable to track that. You also don't need x, lastGuess, and nextGuess. Your x is your next guess, so let's clean that up too. You also want your last guess to be set to x, not to the difference. Implementing these changes looks like this:
In [135]: def sqrt(n):
     ...:     lastGuess = n/2
     ...:     accuracy = 1e-3
     ...:     delta = 1
     ...:     while delta > accuracy:
     ...:         x = (lastGuess + n/ lastGuess) / 2
     ...:         delta = abs(x - lastGuess)
     ...:         lastGuess = x
     ...:         print(x, lastGuess)
     ...:     return x
     ...:

In [136]: sqrt(100)
26.0 26.0
14.923076923076923 14.923076923076923
10.812053925455988 10.812053925455988
10.030495203889796 10.030495203889796
10.000046356507898 10.000046356507898
10.000000000107445 10.000000000107445
Out[136]: 10.000000000107445


The return x ends the while loop in the first loop cycle. Indentation problem ?To check if the desired accuracy is achieved it has to be compared with the absolute value of the difference between the new and old estimates.This is my code for the sqrt function
def sqrt(number):
    accuracy = 0.000001
    estimate = n / 2
    while True:
        new_estimate = (estimate + number / estimate) / 2
        if abs(new_estimate - estimate) < accuracy: 
            return new_estimate
        else:
            estimate = new_estimate

